# What am I doing wrong with the width?

Tags: html, css

I'm currently coding a website with basic html and css, for the sake of having it there, and I'm having a problem with widths.

I set my body to be 1086px width (max width of the elements in my design).

Although my computer's monitor is 1366px wide there's still a scrollbar at the bottom. Anyways to fix this?

overflow:hidden wont work because smaller monitors (1024px) wont be able to see all the content without the scrollbar, so it might be needed.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: FOUND A SOLUTION:

```
{
overflow-y: auto;
overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Can you post some of your actual css code?

Comment: Please post a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) showing the problem

Comment: Are you using a CSS reset?

Comment: Try body{height:100%;}

Answer (score 0):

You should remove any padding and margin from your element in css file.

```
html, body, footer, header etc {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it fixed it in some way. I was using margin: auto; and now the contents arent centered anymore, what do i do?

Answer (score 0):

There are two different box models. You have your width + paddings + margins. Set your box model to border box using the CSS box-sizing property.

```
body {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

At [quirksmode.org](http://quirksmode.org/css/user-interface/boxsizing.html) you can find some examples.

Comment: Didnt work :( I saw what it said and it made sense, but i dont know why it didnt work

Comment: Did you try Browser specific properties? `-moz-box-sizing` or `-webkit-box-sizing` for FF or Chrome/Safari?

Answer (score 0):

Resizing the `body` is not a elegant way. You should use instead of a div container called wrapper and you resize your wrapper. This should also solve your issue.

Have a look at this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/EeJnN/